# Gaussian curvature

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let us take a surface $z =x^3-3x^2+y^2$. If you calculate the critical points on the surface it will come as $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$. Moreover one can find the 
local behavior of the critical points. It will turn out that $(0,0)$ corresponds to a saddle point, and $(2,0)$ corresponds to local min.  Up to here, I am ok.

I take this surface as a Monge Patch $f(u,v) = (u,v,u^3-3u^2+v^2)$ and write the first fundamental form, second fundamental form and compute Gaussian curvature via 
$K = (LN-M^2)/(EG-F^2)$ (standard notation can found in Pressley's "Elementary Differential Geometry").

The problem comes here:

$K(0,0)=-12<0$ saddle ok, BUT

$K(2,0)=12>0$ !

I get confused here. **If it is a local min, then Gaussian curvature is positive?

Why is this notion bothering?  If a surface has local min, isn't it true that at every local min you have negative Gaussian curvature?

Can anyone please explain with some some examples and references?

Comment: The Gaussian curvature is the product of two principal curvatures. At a local min, the sign of the two principal curvatures cannot be opposite. As a result, the Gaussian curvature at a local min is non-negative.

Comment: can you please give an example except the one i gave  where it is local min but Gaussian curvature is positive?" –

Comment: the simplest example is the one given by Jesse. $z = f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$. At $(x,y) = (0,0)$, $f(x,y)$ is reaching a local min. We have $f_{x} = f_{y} = f_{xy} = 0$ and $f_{xx} = f_{yy} = 2$, so $K = 4$. For comparison, consider the surface $z = g(x,y) = -x^2 - y^2$ where $g$ reaches a local max at $(0,0)$, $g_{xx} = g_{yy} = -2$ now has opposite sign from $f_{xx}, f_{yy}$. However, the Gaussian curvature is the product of two principal curvature, their sign cancel out and we get a positive $K = 4$ for both $f$ and $g$ at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

For a surface of the form $z = f(x,y)$, the Gaussian curvature is

$$K = \frac{f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2}{(1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2)^2}.$$

(This is Exercise 8.1.1 in the second edition of Pressley's book.)

By the [Second Derivative Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test), we see that:

- If $K(x,y) < 0$, then $(x,y)$ is a saddle point.
- If $K(x,y) > 0$, then $(x,y)$ is a local maximum or a local minimum (depending on whether $f_{xx}(x,y)$ is negative or positive).

**Example:** Consider the elliptic paraboloids $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z = -x^2 - y^2$.  Both have *positive* Gaussian curvature $K(0,0) = 4 > 0$ at the origin.  However, the first one has a minimum there, and the second has a maximum.

**Example:** The hyperbolic paraboloid $z = x^2 - y^2$ has *negative* Gaussian curvature $K(0,0) = -4 < 0$ at the origin, and has a saddle point there.

Comment: Hello very nice. but i asked something different. it is common notion that concave means neg curvature and convex means positive curvature.  if one draw the picture of this surface (may be in mathematica or maple...)  it clearly see that it is concave. my contradiction comes here.  should we cal it positive gaussian curvature or neg gaussian curvature??

Comment: @ricci1729 That concave/convex vs negative/positive curvature correspondence is for one dimensional objects. For two dimensional surface, the closest correspondence between concave/convex vs curvature is the mean curvature, not the Gaussian curvature!

Comment: @achile hui  thank you very much . can you please give me a ref what you have written for mean curvature

Comment: @ricci1729, the wiki article on [Mean curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature) and the ref there is a start.